# Add new variable to text files if a variable is found using bash

Tags: linux, bash

In multiple text files, let's say a variable is present.

VariableX:
A:1
B:1
D:1

Now, if C:0 has to be added in all these text files just after B:1 (C is inserted on a new line with space aligned), how can this be done for multiple files from bash.

New text files change should look like this:

VariableX:
A:1
B:1
C:0
D:1

This can be done manually by opening each file. But there are many files, is there a way to automate or write a script in bash for this.

git grep VariableX would give all files with VariableX. Is there a way to expand this command  to insert C:0.

Comment: 1. What should happen if there is no setting for `B` in the file, but only, say, `A` and `D`? 2. What should happen if there is already a setting for `C` in the file?

Comment: Also, please post your own attempt to solve the problem. You already know who to find the files which you want to update, so you can concentrate now on how to programmatically insert the new string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given a list of files, use `for` to loop to insert rows.

```
files=$(ls | grep -E '.txt|.py|.java')
for file in ${files}
do
    sed -i '/B:1/aC:0' ${file}
    sed -i '/A:1/d' ${file}
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. For files, is it possible to identify them using extension like .txt. The folder has many different formats. A second question is along the same lines. How to remove A:1 from all files.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The part of the generated file list can be modified according to the actual situation.

Comment: The filename part breaks for blanks in filenames, special characters and more. Use an array, like `files=(*.txt *.py *.java); for file in "{files[@]}"; do` or the glob directly: `for file in *.txt *.py *.java; do` - or even shorter, `for file in *.{txt,py,java}; do`

Comment: ./script.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./script.sh: line 3: `files=(ls | grep -E '.txt')'     I get this error.

Comment: Replaced     files=$(ls | grep -E '.txt|.py|.java')    with files=(*.txt)  and it worked.

Comment: Correction:  Removed   files=$(ls | grep -E '.txt|.py|.java')   and replaced   for file in ${files}  with for file in *.txt    and it worked.